# Concatenation using ## for one string and an integer value in C for microcontroller

Tags: c, concatenation, microcontroller

I need to concatenate a string with an integer.I'm using this code :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define SW_ENUM_VALID_COUNT(x) SW##x##_VALID_COUNT

void main()
{
      int b = 16;
      int SW16_VALID_COUNT=8;
       printf("%d",SW_ENUM_VALID_COUNT(b));
}
```

What should I do in order to have the result of the expression `SW_ENUM_VALID_COUNT(b) <=> SW16_VALID_COUNT` because now the result is `SWb_VALID_COUNT` .

Comment: Do you mean `SW_ENUM_VALID_COUNT(b)` in the `printf()` call? `x` is not defined ...

Answer (score 4):

You can't do this.

The value of a variable (such as `b` in your code) is not available to the preprocessor.